# How more specified html parsing code can be done?

Tags: php, html

I'm dealing this one little problem. Going through task, I want to extract hrefs and titles from html page, but every a tag doesn't have title attribute in it. What I should do if I only want to print out data from tag, that has href and title attributes?

```
 <?php
$searched = file_get_contents('http://technologijos.lt');
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($searched);

$links = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $lnk) 
{
$i++;
$links[] = sprintf(
    ' %s '.$i.'  %s '.$i.'',
     $lnk->getAttribute('title'),
     $lnk->getAttribute('href')
);
echo (implode("\r\n", $links));

}
file_put_contents("data.txt", implode("\n", $links), FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
$searched = file_get_contents('http://technologijos.lt');
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($searched);

$links = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $lnk) 
{
    if (!empty($lnk->getAttribute('title'))  &&  !empty($lnk->getAttribute('href'))){
        $i++;
        $links[] = sprintf(
            ' %s '.$i.'  %s '.$i.'',
             $lnk->getAttribute('title'),
             $lnk->getAttribute('href'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey it almost helped, but we need to use empty() instead is_empty(). Anyway thanks!